# Merging multiple querysets using union is showing error with Count in annotate

Tags: python, django, django-views, union

I have a simple Django app and I am trying to merge multiple querysets using **union** but one of my queryset contains **annotate** with **Count**.

I mean it is showing

> each UNION query must have the same number of columns
> LINE 1: ...::date GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 15 DESC) UNION (SELECT

I am using **Count** in annotate most liked blog post and most viewed blog post like

```
filter_blog_posts = Blog.objects.annotate(f=Count("likes") + Count("views"))
```

and other query which I am merging with is

```
new_blogs = Blog.objects.order_by("-date")
```

and like

```
merged_q = Blog.objects.none()

merged_q = merged_q.union(filter_blog_posts)
merged_q = merged_q.union(new_blogs)
```

and when I remove *annotate* then it is working fine but not with it.

I saw many topics on *showing error with annotate with union* like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60562759/incorrect-results-with-annotate-values-union-in-django)

and I also tried with it by adding values but my other queries will also need to be changed but I don't want to limit the fields.